# Migrating Redis to Kubernetes from docker containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, redis

Currently we are running our sentinel based redis  deployment as docker containers. So far docker containers are working fine but as part of our new enhancement we are moving all our services to Kubernetes (K8S).

I am not sure if K8s is officially supported for Redis or not.  Please suggest if we can do this in production ?

If not in production then is it safe to migrate in other engineering environments like SIT / QA/ UAT etc

Comment: what's the present orchestrator? if the current one is production safe for you, I don't see any reason why k8s won't be...

Comment: It also exists ready to use helm charts from bitname for redis or redis cluster to deploy a redis. If you're not so familiar with kubernetes and/or helm better run it on test and development environment for a while. Try some stress test and see how it behaves. If it is stable enough for you and fast enough. Check the documentation for the helm charts and set the settings for your personal needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, Redis can be safely deployed to a K8s cluster and serve in production**. Please note that K8s under the hood is doing very similar things to your current Docker installation, only that container-, storage- and routing-orchestration is automated.

In order to install Redis, I recommend using the [Helm Chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis) from Bitnami.